# HAProxy - Redirect HTTPS for OAuth (Azure)

Tags: azure, https, haproxy, entra-id, oauth

I need help to solve my issue.

What I want to achieve is

**http**://abc.contoso.com -> **https**://abc.contoso.com 
(Force redirection HTTP to HTTPS)

My problem is that the URI needed for Azure OAuth 2.0 authorization endpoint doesn’t match.

The accepted URI as destination when returning authentication responses (tokens) after successfully authenticating users must be: https://abc.contoso.com/signin-oidc

But HAProxy sends the HTTP form as below:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/bdeebc-dd/oauth2/authorize?client_id=fd&**redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fabc.contoso.com%2Fsignin-oidc**&response_type=id_token&scope=openid profile&response_mode=form_post

What should I do to have the HTTPS form (redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fabc.contoso.com%2Fsignin-oidc) instead of HTTP for OAuth ?

My config is

Front-end

> frontend public_front_end
>   bind *:80
>   mode http
>   option forwardfor
>   redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }
>
> frontend public_secured_front_end
>   bind *:443 ssl crt
>   /etc/haproxy/certs

Back-end

> use_backend abc-api if { hdr(host) -i abc.contoso.com }
>
> backend abc-api
>
> mode http
>
> http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https
>
> server webserver01 192.168.0.1:4569 check
>
> option forwardfor

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be the backend that's sending "https://login.microsoftonline.com/bdeebc-dd/oauth2/authorize?client_id=fd&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fabc.contoso.com%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=id_token&scope=openid profile&response_mode=form_post" ?   I don't see HaProxy doing that.

Comment: Yes, the backend is using the OAuth endpoint and I just need HAProxy to redirect the HTTPS URL to the backend instead of the HTTP one (I think?) so the endpoint can use the right authorized URI.

Comment: Why don't you make the backend use "redirect=h t t p s ://abc.contoso.com/signin-oidc"

Comment: How can I put in in HAProxy language?

Comment: You need to change the backend configuration, not the haproxy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the Azure AD application you have setup to do this authentication to add a reply URL for the https endpoint.